# Execute program from upload

Tags: perl, pipe, stdin

This is mainly curiousity. I may implement it, not sure.

I had this idea... Rather than leave a script on a server, per chance a hacker got to it, I could send the full script to the server from a secondary site, run it, and then delete it. OK in theory ...

The LWP::UserAgent on the 'sending' server would need to connect to a script on the 'receiving' server. The way I would do it at present would be to save the incoming param to a file using open filehandle etc, then a "require" to run the script, followed by an unlink to destroy the file.

```
 $d=param('d');open (D, ">sc.pl");print D $d;close(D);require "sc.pl";unlink "sc.pl";
```

But a hacker could put a suitable "print" between most of those entries, and see what data was being sent.

So I wondered if a similar thing could be achieved WITHOUT writing the code to a file, ie to be executed whilst in memory. It might have something to do with a "while(<>){" or a pipe from STDIN to ???

Just a thought

Comment: By writing a server to receive and execute arbitrary software you'll create a far, far bigger security hole than having a program sitting on a disk of a secured server. Unless your goal is to protect your code from being stolen? In which case I have to ask why your code is worth adding a glaring security hole. And all this is predicated on the idea that someone already owns your server. I would suggest cutting this whole thing down to just "how can I execute Perl code from memory" or "how can I ensure the code my server runs is my own".

Comment: If it is not safe to store your program on disk, how is it safe to have it in memory?

Answer (score 4):

The goal here seems to not be to secure the server, but to protect your source code from being stolen. That's the first flawed premise: ***hackers want your data, not your code***. Hackers rarely care about your source code except to find security holes (which, if they control your server, they've already found). They're not stealing your code for industrial espionage, they want your data to either sell or hold ransom. Credit cards. Customer information. Passwords. Encryption keys. Any of that.

Second, if this theoretical hacker can alter the server code to add `print` statements then executing the program from memory or STDIN won't help that.  If they control the server code they can print whatever they want no matter where the server reads it from.  ***If they can edit the code, they can replace the entire server program***.

This idea is a non-starter.  You need to rethink your premises.